# Part of my Mesh won't follow the rig (i used autorig pro add on)

Tags: mesh, rigging, add-on, auto-rig-pro

I tried to build bone myself for facial rig (actually for mouth) and I used autorig pro add on, I add more bones and connect to original rig, it worked and follow the main bone, but when I bind it the mesh won't follow the bone.

[image]

after "Match to Rig" I bind it, and the mesh following well until I move the jaw, and both of lip controller and the mesh won't follow it, the mesh only following the head controller

[image: mesh following head]

this is how I move jaw controller

[image]

Am I doing wrong or missed the steps, please tell me to fix this
and this is file https://gofile.io/d/QFCOCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that are responsible for this.

1. When you created the bones you did not mark them as deform bones.
2. You do not have vertex groups corresponding to any of the new bones that you created.

To fix 1, tick the Deform checkbox in the Bone Properties tab of the Properties Editor.
[image]

To fix 2, create a vertex group with the same name as each of the deformation bones that you created. Then, use the 3D viewport's weight paint mode to set the vertex group weights. These weights control the influence of the corresponding bone.

Comment: IT WORKS !!!  Thanks for the advice. But I still wondering, if three of the mouth bones should use Deform to move a skin, why not for the other bone
Is that because the other bones are origins from autorig ? or maybe there's something else ?